# Go Away To College

Tags: meaning, prepositions

For this pair of sentences:

> 1. He ***went*** to college.
> 2. He ***went away*** to college.

How is "*go away*" different from "*go*"?

Answer (score 4):

You may stay at home and go to college, if the college you are attending is in your home town; to go *away* to college means to leave home to attend college.

Comment: Would the same distinction apply for "***go*** to a party" and "***go away*** to a party"?

Comment: @meatie Probably not; a party is a pretty transient event, while going away to college implies taking up residence out of town. We'd probably say just "I went to a party in" wherever: New York, Boston, London ...

Comment: I might be squeezing in one sub-question too many.  But is "go **off** to college" the same as "go **away** to college"?

Comment: @meatie Yes, exactly.

Comment: @meatie - RE: _"I might be squeezing in one sub-question too many"_ - I think you are probably right on that one.